# Force an async WebRequest to flush its buffer c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httpwebrequest, flush

I have the following connection code:

```
_request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(complianceUrl);
_request.Method = "GET";

var authInfo = string.Format("{0}:{1}", _username, _password);
authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
_request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + authInfo);

// set stream parameters
_request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
_request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
_request.Accept = "application/json";
_request.ContentType = "application/json";
_request.ReadWriteTimeout = 30000;
_request.AllowReadStreamBuffering = false;

_request.Timeout = 30; //seconds, sends 15-second heartbeat.
_asyncCallback = HandleResult;    //Setting handleResult as Callback method...
_request.BeginGetResponse(_asyncCallback, _request);    //Calling BeginGetResponse on
```

This works fine, and the buffer fills with data and while I have large volumes of data this is fine. But with low volumes of data it takes a while for the buffer to fill up and I want to periodically flush the buffer if I have not had any activity in a while.

I tried to do that this way:

```
_request.GetRequestStream().FlushAsync();
```

But this is wrong as it tells me I am causing a ProtocolViolationException I guess as this is a GET Verb?

Can anyone tell me how to forcibly cause the connection to dump the buffer to the client?

Handling response code added:

```
private void HandleResult(IAsyncResult result)
{
    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse) _request.EndGetResponse(result))
    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var compressedBuffer = new byte[BlockSize];

        while (stream != null && stream.CanRead)
        {
            var readCount = stream.Read(compressedBuffer, 0, compressedBuffer.Length);

            // if readCount is 0, then the stream must have disconnected.  Process and abort!
            if (readCount == 0)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What buffer are you talking about? I don't see any reading or writing code here.

Comment: Added code for handling the buffer, but this is asynchronous, so it waits until the buffer is full, on the server side, and then sends the lot. I need to force a flush on the connection.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? This code looks fine. It drains the stream and correctly detects when the stream is depleted (readCount == 0). Are you doing some kind of long polling or slow streaming over HTTP?

Comment: Async connection, it sits and waits till the buffer is full before it flushes to the client, which is fine during high volume stuff, but I want to be able to force the connection to flush the buffer at will.

Comment: Then we probably need to look at the server which is sending the data. The client cannot cause the implementation of the server to make socket write calls.

Comment: Server is completely out of my control, the issue I sit at this line of code var readCount = stream.Read(compressedBuffer, 0, compressedBuffer.Length); until the buffer is full. I need to sit there until the buffer is fall, or a timeout period is hit and then flush the buffer. Ideally be able to manually force a flush.

Comment: When a timeout occurs, what do you want to do with the data received so far? (Also, Read does not block until the buffer is full. It gives you anything that arrives immediately.)

Comment: I sit and wait on the read line for minutes, while it waits for the buffer to be full, once full I then move onto the next section of code. Maybe I am mistaken in how it works under the hood, but from what I am seeing, I sit on that line until the buffer is full.

Comment: When a timeout occurs, what do you want to do with the data received so far? Do you want to send it somewhere else or abort the connection or what happens then?

Comment: This is a streaming service provided by a 3rd party, they send me "messages" and during high volume the come through fine, during low volume I Have to wait for enough messages to turn up to then process them, which can take 20 odd minutes which is no good for me. I need to be able to tell the service to send me the data so I can process the few messages that are then and then sit waiting for another read. The 3rd party service send 15 second heartbeats CRLF which will also eventually fill up the buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to make the server side of an HTTP call send you data in a particular way. Neither HTTP nor TCP have provisions for that. You have to take what you get, or talk to the vendor.

`Read` does not block until a buffer is full. It gives you what arrives immediately. This behavior is well known, this is not a guess of mine.

> The 3rd party service send 15 second heartbeats CRLF which will also eventually fill up the buffer.

This sounds like the service is doing what you want. If that is true, the problem must be in your code. But not in the code shown in the question. Try this:

```
    while (true)
    {
        var readCount = stream.Read(compressedBuffer, 0, compressedBuffer.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(readCount);
    }
```

This should show 2 bytes every 15 seconds. If not, the vendor is at fault. If yes, you are.

`while (stream != null && stream.CanRead)` this is weird because none of these conditions can become false. And even if they become false, what do you do about it?! This should be `while (true)` plus `break` on stream depletion.

```
// if readCount is 0, then the stream must have disconnected.
```

This condition means that the remote side has orderly finished their sending of the HTTP response.

Comment: I added that code, and I made my buffer size 10 bytes.


15:48:17 READ: 10BYTES
15:49:32 READ: 10BYTES

If they are sending CRLF every 15 seconds I should get more reads as you suggest, I get the data when the buffer is full

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your help on this. What I am trying to do should be easy, I feel it has something to do with the async connection

Comment: Streaming seems to basically work: http://pastebin.com/zpZ4J6QM If this is gzip compressed then you cannot get small chunks anymore (I just notice). Disable all compression. Indeed, if I enable compression then I get the behavior you mention. Case closed :)

Comment: Confirmed, gzip compression is not my friend!!  I will have to have a re-think on how I do this. Will mark this answer as correct! Thanks again for the help!

Comment: just in case you were interested, I got this to work manually deflating the gzip stream.

Comment: That *might* work but only if the server encodes the gzip stream just right so that you can decode it on the client byte-by-byte. Normally, gzip buffers data and does not allow to flush at arbitrary positions.

Comment: I am using this to connect to the GNIP Firehose, and have been testing this for the past several hours, so far I have not anything go wrong. But understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, you can read and deflate manually doing the following:

```
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse) _request.EndGetResponse(result))
using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (var compressedMemory = new MemoryStream())
using (var uncompressedMemory = new MemoryStream()) // Added new memory stream
using (var gzipStream = new GZipStream(compressedMemory, CompressionMode.Decompress))
{
    var compressedBuffer = new byte[BlockSize];

    while (stream != null && stream.CanRead)
    {
        var readCount = stream.Read(compressedBuffer, 0, compressedBuffer.Length);

        compressedMemory.Write(compressedBuffer.Take(readCount).ToArray(), 0, readCount);
        compressedMemory.Position = 0;

        gzipStream.CopyTo(uncompressedMemory); // use copy to rather than trying to read

        var outputString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(uncompressedMemory.ToArray());
        Debug.WriteLine(outputString);

        uncompressedMemory.Position = 0;
        uncompressedMemory.SetLength(0);

        compressedMemory.Position = 0;
        compressedMemory.SetLength(0); // reset length
    }
}
```